# Using Capybara with Headless in Windows OS

Tags: ruby, windows, capybara, headless-browser

I am using headless gem to run Capybara without opening browser in Linux. Headless uses xvfb. Is there something similar for Windows OS or Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both capybara-webkit and poltergeist run just fine on a mac.

Poltergeist uses [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org) to do the heavy lifting, which is available on windows so poltergeist could probably be made to work there, although its documentation says windows isn't supported.

Capybara-webkit lists 32bit windows as a community supported platform, so it should hopefully work there.

Comment: Poltergeist doesn't worked as expected in finding elements, but webkit is fine.